# Parse Values from HTML

Tags: jquery, html, parsing

i must parse the values from this HTML Source: How can I do that with jQuery/JS in a loop?

"attributelist--key" is the target DB Columnname.

```
<dl class="attributelist-striped">
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">value</dd>
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum1:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">value1</dd>
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum2:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">value2</dd>
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum3:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">value3</dd>
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum4:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">value4</dd>
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum5:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">value5</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Anderson, nothing yet, since I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse html using jquery **$.parseHTML()** function

```js
var html='<dl class="attributelist-striped"><dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum:</dt><dd class="attributelist--value">value</dd><dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum1:</dt> <dd class="attributelist--value">value1</dd> <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum2:</dt>   <dd class="attributelist--value">value2</dd>  <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum3:</dt> <dd class="attributelist--value">value3</dd> <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum4:</dt> <dd class="attributelist--value">value4</dd><dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum5:</dt><dd class="attributelist--value">value5</dd></dl>'

var p=$.parseHTML(html)
var z=p[0].children
for(var i=0;i<z.length;i++){ console.log(z[i].innerHTML)}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function to get `key` or `value` values separately:

```js
$('.attributelist-striped dt.attributelist--key').each(function(){

    console.log($(this).text());
})

$('.attributelist-striped dd.attributelist--value').each(function(){

    console.log($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<dl class="attributelist-striped">
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">value</dd>
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum1:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">value1</dd>
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum2:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">value2</dd>
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum3:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">value3</dd>
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum4:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">value4</dd>
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Lorem Ipsum5:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">value5</dd>
</dl>
```